# How do I get a div to automatically adjust to an image size?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a portfolio for someone and their work is going to be displayed in boxes that will be clickable so you can view the actual size of the image on a separate page.

Instead of creating multiple pages with different HTML box sizes, how do i create one page, with an auto adjustable html box to showcase a persons work?

I pretty much need the HTML to adjust to the image size instead of adjusting the HTML box's size to fit the image. How do I do this or what would I need to reference to learn this?

Comment: Hey, please add your code it will be easier to help

Comment: Do you need a way to show each image after clicking or a way to arrange the thumbnails? If you are open to third party js plugins, I think fancybox.js and isotope.js can help in the corresponding case.

Comment: I don't have any code to add. I'm looking for info on how to get a div to do what I need it to do.

Comment: Can you explain why is the div needed?

Comment: @AgustínDorado Yes, I'm trying to display a full sized image after clicking a div that shows the image in the div's set size.

Comment: As i understand you want to show img in full resolution? Why do you need a div to surround it? If you really need to match the div size to img, then you can get the img width/height with javascripts `document.getElementById('my-img').width //and .height` and set div style to same values, using same functions.

Comment: @Cray

I created an HTML box with the div. The div has the partial size of an image. I need to be able to click on it, then be taken to another page where another div displays the image in it's full size.

Comment: Then might I suggest a lightbox? There are multiple libraries for that, like [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/), [lightbox](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), and [Featherlight](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/). You can also check [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp) on creating a lightbox on your own.

Comment: @Cray

Yes I would like to display the image in full resolution in a second page after clicking on the initial div. I need a div tag to surround image because I will be able to adjust the position of the div if needed.  Or do I not need this at all?

Comment: @AgustínDorado

Hmm I think lightbox might be a good option but I'm still learning JS and I don't know how to use libraries and have zero knowledge in jquery.